# Loading json data with Fetch to pass it to React Component as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

So I'm struggling with this task for a while and I really can not know what to do.
The problem is when i try to fetch the data from "/menu/items" and then pass it as prop to Card.js I get the information that "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')" in Card.js.

So I have to Components:

Menu.js

```
const Menu = (props) => {
  const [orders, onAddOrder] = useState([]);
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  });

  const getItems = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/menu/items");
    const data = await response.json();
    setMenuItems(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="menu">
      <div className="menu-main__container">
        <article>
          <Card order={menuItems[0]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[1]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[2]} />
        </article>
        <article>
          <Card order={menuItems[3]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[4]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[5]} />
        </article>
        <article>
          <Card order={menuItems[6]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[7]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[8]} />
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

which is parent component of Card Component

Card.js

```
const Card = (props) => {
  const [order, onAdd] = useState(props.order);

  const onAddOrderHandler = () => {
    console.log(order);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container__order">
      <div className="order__details">
        <img src={KebapImg} className="details__img" />
        <h3>{props.order.name}</h3>
        <p>{props.order.desc}</p>
        <div className="details__price-buy">
          <h1>{props.order.price}zł</h1>
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Take it!"
            className="price-buy__btn"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

/menu/items as json file:

```
{
      id: 1,
      name: "iKebap Pro Max Super",
      price: 22,
      desc: "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "iKebap Pro Max",
      price: 21,
      desc: "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "iKebap Classic",
      price: 15,
      desc: "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "iKebap California Reaper",
      price: 18,
      desc: "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "iKebap Overpriced",
      price: 37,
      desc: "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "iKebap Small",
      price: 10,
      desc: "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit",
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: "iKebap Wege",
      price: 17,
      desc: "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit",
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "iKebap American",
      price: 16,
      desc: "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit",
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "iKebap Góralski",
      price: 17,
      desc: "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipsicing elit",
    }
```

All I want to do is to pass the fetched item to prop and render it as a new component.

Comment: If you log `response` then, `data` in `Menu.js`. What do you get back? Same with props in `Card.js`.

Comment: menuItems is undefined on the first render, and as you are not using map or reduce to render its content (I guess you should), each order is undefined too, so you can't access its attributes, name in this case. You can add this line before the return on the Card component: `if (!props.order) return null`. This will prevent the component for rendering, if it has not a proper order prop.

Comment: I get back a list of objects, but when I pass it to ```Card.js``` it shows up an TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: @maxpsz Thank's a lot! It works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, add an empty dependency array in the useEffect, cause you don't wanna run it on every re-render.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
}, []);
```

Second, you are indeed trying to access an undefined property. On first render you are still resolving the fetch. So your `menuItems` array is still empty, and you're passing undefined values `menuItems[0]`.

All you need to do is waiting for the next render.

```
const Menu = (props) => {
  const [orders, onAddOrder] = useState([]);
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, []);

  const getItems = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/menu/items");
    const data = await response.json();
    setMenuItems(data);
  };

  // ADD THIS LINE
  if (!menuItems.length) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return (
    <div className="menu">
      <div className="menu-main__container">
        <article>
          <Card order={menuItems[0]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[1]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[2]} />
        </article>
        <article>
          <Card order={menuItems[3]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[4]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[5]} />
        </article>
        <article>
          <Card order={menuItems[6]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[7]} />
          <Card order={menuItems[8]} />
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to do is export the json and import it on parent and pass the json as props in card.

After that you can map the props json and distribute it on what ever you want.

Using fetch you need to use UseEffect after fetching it store it in useState and pass it on Card component.

Comment: I did it in ```getItems()``` method. I fetched the data, then received the data as json and I've setted it as ```menuItems```.

Comment: I tried to pass it to Card Component but when I did it I get the TypeError: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')".

Comment: Console.log the props from card component and see it on browser developer tool.

Comment: And also check it order is empty or not.